# FBJS addClassName removeClassName not working

Tags: javascript, tabs, fbml, fbjs

I'm trying to add and remove classes to tabs when people click on them. This is what I have right now and it does absolutely nothing..!

```
<script> 
<!-- 
function toggleClasses() {
   tab1 = document.getElementById("tab1");
   tab2 = document.getElementById("tab2");
   tab3 = document.getElementById("tab3");
   tab4 = document.getElementById("tab4");

   tab1.removeClassName("bstTabSelected").addClassName("bstTab");
   tab2.removeClassName("bstTabSelected").addClassName("bstTab");
   tab3.removeClassName("bstTabSelected").addClassName("bstTab");
   tab4.removeClassName("bstTabSelected").addClassName("bstTab");

}
//--> 
</script>
```

I'm calling it with:

```
<a href="#" id="tab1" onclick="toggleClass()" class="bstTabSelected" clicktoshow="tab1" clicktohide="tab2,tab3,tab4">Tab 1</a>
```

I can't seem to figure it out.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You function is named `toggleClasses` (plural) where your click event calls `toggleClass` (singular)

### EDIT

Are you using Firefox and Firebug?  FBJS doesn't ovewrite the console, which is super handy.  Make sure your function is running at all

```
function toggleClasses()
{
  console.log( 'Hello from toggleClasses!' );
}
```